# Find two numbers in an array whose sum equals a target sum

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Write a function that when passed an array and a target sum return,
> efficiently with respect to time used, two distinct zero-based
> indices of any of two numbers, whose sum is equal to the target sum.
> If there are no two numbers, the function should return null. For
> example, `findTwoSum([ 3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9 ], 10)` should return an array
> containing any  of the following pair indices:
>
> - 0 and 3 as 3+7 =10
> - 1 and 5 as 1+9=10
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @param {number[]} numbers The array of numbers.
>  * @param {number} sum The required target sum.
>  * @return {number[]} An array of 2 indices. The indices of the two > elements whose sum is equal to sum.
>  */
>  function findTwoSum(numbers, sum) {
>     // Your code goes here
>  }
>  
>  const indices = findTwoSum([ 3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9 ], 10);
>  console.log(indices);
> ```

I wanted to approach it with a for loop to sum each one of the numbers as:

```
    let taken= Set()
    for (i=0;i < numbers.length;i++){
      numbers[i]
    }
```

But I still don't know how to make one number sum with the others.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour], look around, and read the [help], esp. *[ask]*. Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and **give it a try**. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it, [search](/help/searching) [thoroughly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site:stackoverflow.com), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help. [More here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/).

Comment: Side note: You need to declare `i`, and `Set` cannot be called without `new`.

Comment: Hello T.J, thanks for the info. I am actually learning by my self so It's been a little difficult. I'll try to take a look to other questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the inverse and see if there is a number in the array that is equal to the subtraction of the current number with the final sum

```
 function findTwoSum(numbers, sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      const num = numbers.indexOf(sum - numbers[i])
      if (num !== -1) return [i, num];
  }
 }
 
 const indices = findTwoSum([ 3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9 ], 10);
 console.log(indices);
```

Comment: Note: This only works for scenarios where you need to find 2 numbers. If you need to find n numbers, it would be better to use other strategies.

Answer (score 1):

this is solution with O(n^2) time complexity

```js
function findTwoSum(numbers, sum) {
  let indices = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] === sum)
        indices.push([numbers[i], numbers[j]]);
    }
  }
  return indices;
}

const indices = findTwoSum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10);
console.log(indices);
```

Comment: Isn't that worst case scenario?

Comment: Hello @Extraterrestrial, What do you mean by worst case scenario?

Comment: @Extraterrestrial No, it's not worst case scenario. It's O(n^2) in average.

Comment: Okay I got it...

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getTwoNumberThatAddUpToTargetNumber(array, targetNumber) {
const arrayOfTuples = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[i] + array[j] === targetNumber) {
      arrayOfTuples.push([array[i], array[j]]);
    }
  }
}
return arrayOfTuples;
```

}